# Koa + TypeScript: Property 'body' does not exist on type Request

Tags: typescript, koa, koa-bodyparser

I wanted to use koa & koa-bodyparser with TypeScript but whenever I access `ctx.request.body` I get an error that `body` doesn't exist on type `Request`

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import Router from 'koa-router'
import bodyparser from 'koa-bodyparser'

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

const data = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet']

app.use(bodyparser())
router.post('/', (ctx, next) => {
  const phrase = ctx.request.body; // Property 'body' does not exist on type Request
  if (typeof phrase === 'string') {
    ctx.response.body = data.filter(element => element.includes(phrase))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run `npm install --save-dev @types/koa-bodyparser` in a terminal while in the directory where your package.json is

This package contains types introduced by koa-bodyparser (such as request.body)

Answer (score 3):

If you're here from the future, there's an additional problem that can cause this. Scenario:

1. Past you: Install koa, koa-bodyparser, @types/koa, @types/koa-bodyparser
2. Code: Everything works great
3. Today you: Time for an upgrade; update [all of those packages]
4. Code: `Property 'body' does not exist on type Request`

---

TL;DR: yarn.lock

---

## What's happened?

Digging deeper, in your node_modules, you see:

```
- node_modules/
  - @types/koa/
  - @types/koa-bodyparser/
      - node_modules/
      -   @types/koa/
```

## Why does that *matter*?

Let's take a look at @koa-bodyparser to find out. Here are the relevant lines, and how it works:

```
import * as Koa from "koa";

declare module "koa" {
    interface Request {
        body?: any;
        rawBody: string;
    }
}
```

What it does is define extra parameters for the Request type on the `koa` package that you're using, right? Well, normally, but not quite. It also has a dependency on `@types/koa` because of the `import` at the top. What it actually does is define extra parameters for the Request type on the `koa` object that IT uses, and since it's now using a different version than you are, you don't have that benefit anymore.

## OK why did this *happen*, then?

When you first installed everything, yarn built a dependency tree, looked at the versions in each package.json and ended up with this:

```
"@types/koa@*", "@types/koa@^2.13.1":
  version "2.13.1"
  ... resolved, integrity, dependencies, etc.
```

The `@types/koa@^2.13.1` will be whatever version you installed in your package.json. The `@types/koa@*` is what's in @types/koa-bodyparser.

And then when you updated, yarn built a dependency tree, looked at the versions in each package.json and compared that to what it already had. Your code now says `@types/koa@^2.13.5`, so yarn needs to install a new version for it. @types/bodyparser still says `@types/koa@*`, which is already accounted for in the yarn.lock, and so you end up with a yarn.lock that looks like this:

```
"@types/koa@*":
  version "2.13.1"
  ... resolved, integrity, dependencies, etc.

"@types/koa@^2.13.5":
  version "2.13.5"
  ... resolved, integrity, dependencies, etc.
```

And now that you're not using the same version, one gets installed in your node_modules, and the other gets installed in the node_modules of the package that requested it.

## So how do I *fix* it?

The easiest way? Delete the whole block of `@types/koa@*`from your yarn.lock file and run `yarn` again. You'll now end up with this:

```
"@types/koa@*", "@types/koa@^2.13.5":
  version "2.13.5"
  ... resolved, integrity, dependencies, etc.
```

And everything is happy again until next time.